# Envio de datos de HTML a Firebase

Tags: firebase

estoy creando una aplicación móvil y necesito enviar datos numéricos, tipo push, con HTML a Firebase, el problema es que los envía con comillas, y al recibirlos en la aplicación móvil genera error debido a esas comillas, ya que las variables que reciben los datos son de tipo double. Habrá algún método para enviar los mensajes sin comillas?. La función que estoy utilizando es la siguiente, gracias.

```
[Reference messages collection]
var messageRef = 
firebase.database().ref('users').push(dato1, dato2);

[Save message to firebase] 
function saveMessage(dato1, dato2){
  var newMessageRef = messageRef.push();
  newMessageRef.set({
    dato1: dato1,
    dato2: dato2

  });
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, ¿guardar contenido HTML en un campo declarado double? Lo lógico sería armar un objeto estructurado según cada tipo de dato y mandarlo a Firebase ¿no?

Comment: Muchas gracias A. Cedano, eso está resuelto, el problema es que los datos los envía con comillas, y esos datos los recibe una aplicación Android, pero las comillas me dan error y cierran la aplicación, entonces lo que necesito es quitarlas.